# Breaking a string pointer till a marker in c

Tags: c

I have a pointer char * c = "I - need - to - do - this - break". I need to break it according to the '-' such that in each iteration I get an output as "I" then "I -need" then " I - need - to" and so on till the whole string.
Any help?

Comment: You CANNOT modify a ***String Literal***. Make that `char c[] = "I - need - to - do - this - break";` or you will SegFault when you try and modify `c`. Now, you can do this without any modification at all -- but you must take care to understand the difference. What have you tried?

Comment: Okay david, so first I'll store this in an char array. Then I'll loop through the array to find first '-' and would store the string found till that point. But the problem is the output string gets bigger in each iteration so I need a way to deal with that.

Comment: Store it in a char array, loop over the chars in `c`, when your previous char is a non-space, set the current char to `'\0'` (the *nul-terminating* char) and print `c`, then restore the current char, and skip any `' '` or `'-'` until you find the next real char, step forward until you encounter the next case, rinse repeat until you run out of chars.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to make `c` mutable and not a pointer to a *String Literal*. That way all you need to do is work down the string (either using a pointer or an index) and keep track of whether you are in a word or not in a word. When you hit a space (or hyphen if you get rid of the spaces), if you are in a word, save the current char, overwrite the current char in the array with `'\0'` to terminate the string at the current character and print it. Restore the current character in the array and repeat until you run out of characters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char c[] = "I - need - to - do - this - break", /* an array */
        *p = c;     /* pointer to current char */
    int in = 0;     /* flag for in/out of word */

    while (*p) {    /* loop over each char */
        if (*p == ' ' || *p == '-') {   /* if a space or hyphen */
            if (in) {                   /* if in a word */
                char current = *p;      /* save current char */
                *p = 0;                 /* nul-terminate array at current */
                puts (c);               /* print array */
                *p = current;           /* restore current in array */
                in = 0;                 /* set flag out of word */
            }
        }
        else {          /* otherwise, not a space or hyphen */
            in = 1;     /* set flag in word */
        }
        p++;            /* advance to next char */
    }

    if (in)             /* if in word when last char reached */
        puts (c);       /* output full string */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/incremental
I
I - need
I - need - to
I - need - to - do
I - need - to - do - this
I - need - to - do - this - break
```

**Using a Non-Mutable String Literal**

If you must use a non-mutable *String Literal*, then the approach is largely the same. The only difference being you cannot nul-terminate the original string, so you are left using another pointer (or index) to output each character from the beginning until you reach the current using `putchar` (or getting the number of characters from `p - c` and then copying to a buffer to nul-terminate and output all at once). Simply looping until you reach the current and using `putchar` for output is about as easy as anything else, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *c = "I - need - to - do - this - break",  /* string literal */
        *p = c;     /* pointer to current char */
    int in = 0;     /* flag for in/out of word */

    while (*p) {    /* loop over each char */
        if (*p == ' ' || *p == '-') {   /* if a space or hypen */
            if (in) {                   /* if in a word */
                char *wp = c;           /* get pointer to start */
                while (wp < p)          /* loop until you reach current */
                    putchar (*wp++);    /* output each char & increment */
                putchar ('\n');         /* tidy up with newline */
                in = 0;                 /* set flag out of word */
            }
        }
        else {          /* otherwise, not a space or hyphen */
            in = 1;     /* set flag in word */
        }
        p++;            /* advance to next char */
    }

    if (in)             /* if in word when last char reached */
        puts (c);       /* output full string */
}
```

(the output is the same)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: There's also `printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p - c), c);` which, give or take an off-by-one, prints (at most) the specified number of characters.